# how to reference a dom node using forward ref where the two components are in the same level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-forwardref

When i press enter on *textarea* in **TextArea** component the focus should go in *textarea* of **Editor.js** component.
this is my parent component.

```
  const Content = () => {
      
      return (
        <div>
          <TextArea />
          <Editor />
        </div>
      )
    }
```

textarea.js  (first child)

```
 const TextArea = () => {
        function handleChange(e){
         //if e.target.value will be that of enter , bring focus to textarea of Editor.js  
        }
        return (
        <div>
            <textarea
            onChange={handleChange} 
            />
        </div>
        )
```

Editor.js

```
 const Editor = () => {
            return (
            <div>
                <textarea/>
            </div>
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is How you approach it:

```
const TextArea = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const {editorRef} = props;
  function handleChange(e) {
    //if e.target.value will be that of enter , bring focus to textarea of Editor.js
    if(editorRef.current){
      editorRef.current.focus();
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <textarea ref={ref} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
});

const Editor = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <textarea ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
});

const Content = () => {
  const textAreaRef = useRef();
  const EditorRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <TextArea ref={textAreaRef} editorRef={EditorRef}/>
      <Editor ref={EditorRef} textAreaRef={textAreaRef} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

here is a working sand box which you can test: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-varahamihira-rp84h?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i am getting the floowing error
Warning: forwardRef render functions accept exactly two parameters: props and ref. Any additional parameter will be undefined.
Editor refs is giving undefined

Comment: You can not pass the 3rd parameter(it will be undefined) on forwardRef as shown in Text Area, editorRef can be part of props.

Comment: oops, my bad, try again, I've edited the answer

Comment: @TaghiKhavari i did try that , but i still get editorRef.current as undefined.
this is the error i got 
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Comment: It works fine. just see the demo I attach

Comment: yes , the logic looks perfectly fine.
i think the problem is that i am using slate , a npm library for contentEditable.
so i think i cant ref the div with attribut as contentEditable @TaghiKhavari